# Is something wrong with my use of wc or grep in the linux command line? I"m getting +1 on my char count

Tags: linux, bash, grep, command-line-interface, wc

When I run

```
echo "obase=2;3" | bc | grep -v \n\s | wc -m
```

bash returns 3.  But when I run

```
echo "obase=2;3" | bc
```

bash returns 11.

Why is wc -m one digit high on its count?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The extra character is the trailing newline.**

`wc -m` receives and counts the following three characters: `1` `1` `\n`.

```
$ echo "obase=2;3" | bc | grep -v \n\s | od -c
0000000    1   1  \n                                                    
0000003
```

If you get rid of the newline, the count will be as you're expecting:

```
$ echo "obase=2;3" | bc | grep -v \n\s | tr -d '\n' | wc -m
       2
```

Comment: Just for refresh what is -m for in wc ?

Comment: "-m" means "print number of chars".